# Firebird DB read deleted register after commit

Tags: transactions, firebird, firebird2.5

I have a firebird 2.5 database, and I was wondering if there is a way to rollback a transaction that was commited. Really, I'm asking if someone who could access to firebird database file, can read data that was deleted in a prior commited transaction.
I have a process (stored procedure) that delete some registers and commit. Could this registers be recovery for someone who can access to the database file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple way to recover/rollback committed transactions, however Firebird uses [MVCC (Multi Version Concurrency Control)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control). Deleting (or updating) a record will add a new record version and create a delta recordversion for the previous state of the record.

When no transaction is 'interested' in the old record version, it becomes eligible for garbage collection (which might be done cooperatively when another transaction visits the record, or in the background). However there is no guarantee when this garbage collection occurs.

So if a record is deleted, but hasn't been garbage collected yet (either because there are still transactions with an interest in it, or because the garbage collector hasn't visited the record yet), then it is still possible for people with sufficient skill and knowledge of the internal structure of Firebird to recover the record. Note that even if a record version has been garbage collected, the data itself will be on disk until it is overwritten by another record version.

See also [Firebird for the Database Expert: Episode 4 - OAT, OIT, & Sweep](https://web.archive.org/web/20231004130607/https://ibphoenix.com/resources/documents/design/doc_21)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had read this Episode 4 some days ago, and I think It couldn't be easy to read, but perhaps it will be posible, as you said. If I launch a garbage collection after a delete operation, the problem still go. I could do it only on transaction that I really want to be unrecoverable.

Comment: @briast It might help to know why you need to know: do you need to recover data, or do you want to be sure that a deleted record is not recoverable?

Comment: Hi. I want to be sure that a deleted record is not recoverable.

Comment: The only way to really be sure is to perform a backup and restore after the delete. However I'd say your requirement that you want it to be unrecoverable is rather suspect.

Comment: Suspect? That requirement comes from my customer. It's what he wants. :-)

Comment: Suspect as in that it is a weird and uncommon requirement.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But in a particular delete process he need to be sure it can't be recoverable. As I said, it's what he wants ... ;-))

Comment: Then as I said: backup and restore (using gbak, not nbackup) :)